# Can't submit Facebook Request for App Review - form has unticked criteria

Tags: forms, facebook, permissions

I'm using a plugin (xyzscripts) in wordpress to automatically make a facebook post when I add a blog item to the website.

I need to create a Facebook App to be able to authorise the plugin to be able to this (to login to my facebook admin account and select the page it's to be posted onto from within wordpress)

The instructions have been fine so far and I'm at the stage of submitting the app for review by facebook but the application form needs to be classed as 'complete' before it can be submitted and there are 2 tickboxes which are not ticked and I'm not sure how to get them to tick?! It's not a tickbox that I can select, it seems facebook validates whether the criteria is complete based on the form, so although I think it's complete facebook doesn't and I'm not sure what else to add to make those tickboxes tick... in order to be able select 'submit for review'.

There's a screenshot linked to below showing what I'm referring to, of the tickboxes which aren't ticked.

Has anyone had this problem? Can the form see whats in the video and it already thinks it's not good enough? I have included the words 'pages_manage_posts' and 'pages_read_engagement' in the text describing why the app needs these permissions as I thought that might be a validating factor but nope, still no tick.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

[image of the facebook page showing the tickboxes which aren't ticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Svw.png)

Comment: That self explanatory you need to have 'pages_show_list' and 'pages_read_engagement' permissions too in order to use "pages_manage_posts". Just include those permissions to submit your application.

Comment: _“I have included the words 'pages_manage_posts' and 'pages_read_engagement' in the text”_ - you need to add the actual permissions to your submission, not just “talk” about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have included the words 'pages_manage_posts' and 'pages_read_engagement' in the text

You need to add the actual permissions to your submission, not just “mention” them.

Go to this section in your app dashboard, and click the “request” button next to those two permissions:

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/submission-guide#step-1--select-permissions-and-features

Comment: Ah thanks... so I had just missed out selecting one of the permissions to request... 